# User class, session deleted without reason

Tags: php, mysql, session

I've got a user class and for some reason it sometimes logs me out for no reason.

It for example happens when a page is loading slow and I click on the link another time.

This is my class

```
    public function __construct( $mysqli ) {
        $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
        $this->table = 'users';
        if( isset( $_SESSION['user_id'] ) ) {
            $this->checkSession();
            if( isset( $_SESSION['user_id'] ) ) {
                $this->log('<span class="log_blue">__construct okay</span>');
                $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
            }
            else {
                $this->log('<span class="log_blue">__construct not okay</span>');
                $this->logout();
            }
        }
        else {
            $this->user_id = 0;
        }
    }

    public function checkSession() {
        $this->log('<span class="log_blue">Checking session...</span>');
        $selection = $this->mysqli->query( 'SELECT', $this->table.'_logged_in', array('session_id', 'token'), 'WHERE user_id=? AND user_agent=?', array( $_SESSION['user_id'], $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) );
        if($selection) {
            if( session_id() == $selection[0]['session_id'] and $_SESSION['token'] == $selection[0]['token']) {
                $this->log('<span class="log_blue">Session is okay. Refreshing session.</span>');
                $this->refreshSession();
                return true;
            }
        }
        else {
            $this->log('<span class="log_blue">Session is not okay, deleting session.</span>');
            $this->logout();
        }
    }
    private function refreshSession() {
        session_regenerate_id();
        $token = $this->createToken();
        $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
        $this->mysqli->query( 'UPDATE', $this->table.'_logged_in', array( 'token'=>$token, 'session_id'=>session_id(), 'session_time'=>time() ), 'WHERE user_id=? AND user_agent=?', array( $_SESSION['user_id'], $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) );
        return true;
    }
    public function logout() {
        @session_start();
        $this->log('<span class="log_blue">Deleting session.</span>');
        if( isset( $_SESSION['user_id'] ) ) 
            $this->mysqli->query( 'DELETE', $this->table.'_logged_in', '', 'WHERE user_id=? AND user_agent=?', array( $_SESSION['user_id'], $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) );
        unset( $_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['user_id'] );
        session_destroy();
        $this->user_id = 0;
        return true;
    }

?>
```

Note that I use a class to handle my queries, for information, the query function looks like this

```
public function query( $method, $table, $data='', $where_text='', $where_data='' ) {
```

To debug the problem I've added logs to the user class (`$this->log()`). This results in:

```
Checking session...
Session is okay. Refreshing session.
Checking session...
Session is okay. Refreshing session.
Checking session...
Session is okay. Refreshing session.
Checking session...
Deleting session.
```

It is delete the session, but I can't find why. Any ideas?

Comment: First thing would be to check your PHP.ini settings to session lifespan, the key you should be looking for is: `session.gc_maxlifetime`

Comment: @JamieBicknell, I will do that as soon as I'm home... what should the value be (at least)?

Comment: It's whatever you think is right for your application, if you're getting logged out prematurely due to __construct checking if the session exists then it sounds like the session has expired, so I'd see what it was, and double it

Comment: You could setup your own session handler (http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php) to debug, so you can log the session events better. Especially the garbage collector function.